# What is the best way to get enum string name from integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I need to get string name of enum state by integer value, and i do it next way

```
Order.states.find{|x| x[1] == data['stateId']}
```

Does anybody know better way to do it?

```
enum state: {
         created: 0,
         cancelled: 100,
         complete: 10,
       }
```

Comment: Could you share the enum definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get key name from a enum value in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374174/how-to-get-key-name-from-a-enum-value-in-rails)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Order.states.key(100) => 'cancelled'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that removes the magic number.

```
Order.states.key(Order.states[:cancelled]) => 'cancelled'
```

Comment: this expression does not resolve a problem, if i knew that state is :cancelled, why i would find it in array of states? in my case i have an integer value