# How to get key name from a enum value in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have a enum in my Model that corresponds to column in the database.

The enum looks like:

```
enum efficency: { High: 0, Medium: 1, Low: 2 }
```

How can I get the key from the value

For example, i have the value 0, i need to fetch the value High.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get enum string name from integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839145/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-enum-string-name-from-integer-value)

Comment: @SebastianPalma You're right, but I think that this question, together with its answer, is clearer, so I'm going to vote that the other one is the duplicate.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
Model.efficiencies.key(0) # => 'High'
```

Replace `Model` with the actual name of your model.

Comment: This is an unusual thing to be doing, however. You *might* be asking [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); why do you need to perform this conversion?

Comment: I am running a rspec test. I have set the enum value in the factory file. The keys are used as options of a drop down. So, when running the test, i need to select the key name. But insted it is returning only the value. That is why i need the key name.